# VBA Loop search specific values in a selected range

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to make a small code which would search a provided range of numbers (which is selected with an input box) for codes from a 'dictionary'. All numbers are used as text, because dictionary numbers contain zeroes in front of them. I made small code based on the info I found on the net but it gives me an error 424 on of the lines of code (I will specify it in the code below)

Here is my workflow:

1. Press the button to select the range of cells where the matches from the dictionary will be searched
2. Convert the the selected range to Text
3. Loop search the values from dictionary in the input-box-selected range and highlight the cells with the match.
4. Press another button to reset formatting (to prepare the sheet for pasting another range).

```
    Sub SearchAndFormat_Click()
    Dim Dictionary As Variant
    Dictionary = Range("O1:O671").value 'the dictionary range whose values to be loop searched
            
    Dim r As Range 'input box to select the range where the dictionary values will be searched
    Set r = Application.InputBox("Select range", "Selection Window", Type:=0) '424 error
    r.NumberFormat = "@" 'set input box values format to Text to avoid problems
        
    Dim word As Variant
    For Each word In Dictionary
    r.Find(word).Interior.ColorIndex = 4 'if dictionary values are found in r, add red fill to the cell
    Next
    End Sub
```

And here is the code for the clear formatting button in the previously selected range:

```
Sub ClearFormat_Click()
    r.ClearFormats
End Sub
```

Looking forward to your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is caused because you've selected the wrong return type for the inputbox.

From microsoft's documention on Application.Inputbox (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox):

| Value | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | A formula |
| 1 | A number |
| 2 | Text (a string) |
| 4 | A logical value (True or False) |
| 8 | A cell reference, as a Range object |
| 16 | An error value, such as #N/A |
| 64 | An array of values |

Therefore you just need to change your 0 to an 8:

```
Set r = Application.InputBox("Select range", "Selection Window", Type:=8)
```

EDIT:
To resolve the error 91 in the loop:

```
For Each word In Dictionary
  Set target_cell = r.Find(word)
  If Not target_cell Is Nothing Then
    target_cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
  End If
Next
```

Comment: You are right, It solved the issue, but now I have an error 91 with this line:
`r.Find(word).Interior.ColorIndex = 4`
What would be the right way to address it?

Comment: Error 91 is "object variable not set".

We can see from the code that `r` and `word` are set, so it must be the result of `r.Find(word)` returning nothing (no matching words in the range r).

Assign something like `set target_cell = r.Find(word)` and then test if that is null before applying the colour

Comment: Not sure if this is what you meant, but the test msgbox shows all 'false' even though the there are no matches between the dictionary and the selected range:
`For Each word In Dictionary
        Set target_cell = r.Find(word)
        MsgBox (IsNull(target_cell))
Next word`

Comment: Sorry Kensian, I said null when I meant nothing...
`For Each word In Dictionary
        Set target_cell = r.Find(word)
        If Not target_cell Is Nothing Then
            target_cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4 'if dictionary values are found in r, add red fill to the cell
        End If
Next`
It's hard to read in comments so added to answer.